# Can Winapi always be in use and can run on all versions of windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, native

Sorry I just want opinions, I am not an expert on this, I always use Java to create GUI apps

I learned c ++ since 2011, and there are some c ++ gui libraries that can be used in windows, I think all GUI libraries use winAPI, if that's true, I can make my own GUI library like SDL, wxWidget using WINAPI right? But if I create an app with winAPI, will my application be able to run on the latest windows?

I studied the old book about WinApi entitled "Programming Windows, 5th Edition", I am confused, can WINAPI can be used in windows 10? That's my question, sorry i'm using windows 7

Comment: If the WinAPI couldn't be used in Windows 10, millions of applications world-wide would stop working. Think about it. Then check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com)

Comment: Oh yes, I hope winapi can be used forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell the future to infinity, but winapi will probably stop being used by the heat death of the universe.

It does, however, mostly work on windows 10.

Getting winapi programs into the store takes a bit of extra work.

Comment: Yes thanks, it's very helpful, I think that if I make an application with winapi, can it always be used in all versions of windows? Yes now know the answer,